# Why some linux uses apt-get and some uses yum (which doesn't support apt-get)

Tags: linux

I worked on different flavours of linux (Cent OS, Fedora, Lime Mint, Debian, Rocky etc.,). However why few has apt-get and some supports yum

Can someone explain the background/context and pros/cons?

Thanks

Comment: Developed by different people/companies. That's it. People didn't like other people's approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each new distribution makes its own packaging system, possibly because they're unhappy with features of other distribution's packaging systems and they think they can make a better one.  (See https://xkcd.com/927/ )

Some distributions, rather than starting from scratch, clone an existing distribution, either with or without major changes, and use the upstream distribution's packaging tool.

As a result, Redhat based distributions (RedHat, Fedora, CentOS, Rocky, Alma, others) use rpm, yum, and dnf.

Debian based distributions (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, and many others) use dpkg, apt, and apt-get.

Low level package managers like dpkg and rpm only deal with querying installed packages and installing and removing packages, and possibly building binary packages from source packages.

High level package managers like yum, dnf, apt, etc., also coordinate update plans, download packages from repositories, resolve dependencies between packages, and call their corresponding low level package managers to update and install what they download, and remove no longer needed dependencies.

The current most popular distributions are mostly based on either Debian or RedHat, but there are quite a few others that use different package managers.

A handful of distributions (like Gentoo which uses portage) don't use binary packages at all, and the package manager only deals with source code packages, so installing a package requires compiling.  This has the advantage of possible greater customization and optimization, with the disadvantage that it takes much longer to install and update packages.